# DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color) vs Drawable.setColorFilter(color, mode)

Tags: android, drawable, android-appcompat, porter-duff

What's the difference between those two implementations?

```
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(wrappedDrawable, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, color);
```

and

```
drawable.setColorFilter(color, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```